# Upload bitmap image to server with retrofit

Tags: android, upload, imageview, retrofit

I have to upload an image file after selection from user preferred app (Cameta, Gallery etc). I can show the result intent in the Imageview as Bitmap. Now i want to **upload** this image after a button will be clicked. I used retrofit to do so.
And I follow [ImagePicker](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2) class to collect the image into my Imageview .

Collecting image code:

```
CircleImageView imageViewProfile_Picture;

public void onPickImage(View view) {
    Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
    startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID:
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
            // TODO collect picture and show in Imageview
            imageViewProfile_Picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

To Upload image to server i use Retrofit library

```
// How to get the file object from bitmap 

File file=null;

    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
```

**API Interface**

```
    @Multipart
@POST("/taxiapi/api?")
Call<SignUpResponse> signup(@Part("user_name") RequestBody user_name,
                            @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                            @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                            @Part("action") RequestBody action,
                            @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                            @Part("phone") RequestBody phone,
                            @Part("icard") RequestBody icard,
                            @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                            @Part("profile_picture") RequestBody pic_name);
```

My Question is how to get file obejct from this scenario, after set Imageview from result intent to upload selected picture in server?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToLast();
String photoPath =  cursor.getString(column_index_data);
```

photoPath will be contain  path of the last image captured by camera.

And then `File file = new File(photoPath);`